# How to use thread pool where each thread has its own members

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, threadpool

for simplicity, I have an object (class) which I want to run as thread.
The object has it's own members.

I want to use thread pool to create at 4 threads and run those 4 threads with different parameters each time.

The class (thread class) looks:

```
class CLogicThread {
public:
    CLogicThread();
    void RunLogic();
    void SetParams(int num);
    virtual ~CLogicThread();

private:
    int m_Number = 0;
};

void CLogicThread::RunLogic() {

    m_Number = m_Number + rand() % 2;
    int miliToSleep = rand() % 2000 + 100;
    usleep(miliToSleep);
    std::cout << "Running Thread Id : " << std::this_thread::get_id() << " Value: " << m_Number;

}


void CLogicThread::SetParams(int num) {
    m_Number = num;
}
```

Whenever there is a thread which has finished it's job earlier, it will get a new job to perform (without creating new thread, i.e use one of the vacant threads).
Something like:

```
    Pool pool(4); // I dont have this class and looks for it
    int counter = 0;
    while (true) {
        usleep(10);
        counter++;
        // the next code line will be blocked till new thread is avaliable
        CLogicThread* pLogicThread = pool->GetThreadElement();
        pLogicThread->SetParams(counter);
        pLogicThread->RunLogic();

    }
```

I have looked here:
[Thread pooling in C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15752659/thread-pooling-in-c11)

And here:
[CTPL](https://github.com/vit-vit/ctpl)

but didn't found Pool with my need.
Is there ant open source of Pool I can use ? or do I need to implement it ?

Comment: Make the thread a member of your class.

Comment: What you describe is a worker thread pool, there are hundreds of examples in google.