# In a c++ multithread application set the max number of concurrent thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

I work in a Windows environment (Visual Studio 2019). I want to create a c++ application that has to perform many times: let's say 10000 times. 
I want to implement this using multiple threads and, of coursem I want to limit the number of the concurrent threads let's say 20. 
In other words I want to do the same thing that in a c# application I can easy do with the parallel instruction:

```
public class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {      
       ParallelOptions opt = new ParallelOptions();
       opt.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 20;
        Parallel.For(0, 10000, opt, i =>
        {
            // Do the task
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at [std::for_each](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) and use execution policy `std::execution::par`. I'll create a "good" amount of threads.

Comment: Take a look at OpenMP.

Comment: Create a concurrent queue with work items and spawn 20 threads that pull work off the queue. If the queue is empty, have the threads exit.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15752659/thread-pooling-in-c11 is a very relevant answer for this question, too.

Comment: The optimal degree of parallelism can be determined by calling `std::thread::hardware_concurrency()`. Just create a pool of that many threads and a work queue (with a mutex).

Comment: "_optimal_" differs though. Sometimes it's one thread less than `hardware_concurrency()` and sometimes it may be bigger than that.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ version would probably look like this:

```
std::vector<workpackage> workpackages;

std::for_each(std::execution::par, workpackages.begin(), workpackages.end(), [](auto& wp) {
    // work with workpackage "wp" here
});
```

... but you can't decide how many threads it'll use. If you want more control you can create threads manuallly with `std::thread` and just count how many you have running.