# CTPL Thread pool library how to wait for all threads to finish?

Tags: c++, multithreading, threadpool

```
void runner(int id, int a, int b) {...}

void caller()
{
  static ctpl::thread_pool pool(4);
  for (int i = 0; i < nbThreads; i++) {
    pool.push(runner, a, b);
  }
  pool.stop(true); // this kills all threads, meaning next time this function is called i have to create them again
}
```

So I'm using this library here: https://github.com/vit-vit/ctpl

However, in the example, I did not see any function to synchronize the threads. For `std::thread`, that would be `th.join()`. `pool.get_thread(i).join()` is not the solution; it freezes the because the thread is running always running to accept new commands, which is its intended behavior.

The only way I see that work is `pool.stop(true)`. But if I do this, the threads are destroyed and I have to create them again next time, which defeats the point of a thread pool.

Can someone who use this library show me how to synchronize threads?

Comment: have you read through this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15752659/thread-pooling-in-c11 basically -- There is a difference between a "thread pool" and a collection of threads. I am thinking you want the latter. From the link: `A pool of threads means that all your threads are running, all the time – in other words, the thread function never returns.`

Comment: with the latter, i have to create new threads each time a function is called, which cost time. I'm looking for a way so that threads only need to be created once, then reuse

Comment: ??? why are you trying to stop/join the pool if you need it later?  Just create it once, at program initialization, and then.....don't stop it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as though you misunderstand the usefulness of CTPL.

From CTPL README.md:

> ... The jobs come to the pool dynamically. A job is fetched and deleted
> from the container when there is an idle thread. The job is then run
> on that thread.
>
> A thread pool is helpful when you want to minimize time of loading and
> destroying threads and when you want to limit the number of parallel
> jobs that run simultaneously ...

If you want to run the thread pool once and then return the function once all the threads are done simply do the following:

```
void runner(int id, int a, int b) {...}

void caller()
{
  int nbThreads = 4;
  ctpl::thread_pool pool(4);
  for (int i = 0; i < nbThreads; i++) {
    pool.push(runner, a, b);
  }
}
```

The caller function will not return until the thread_pool's threads have finished. This effectively synchronizes the threads.

---

The benefit of CTPL's thread_pool is you can push a job to the thread pool without worrying about the status of the other threads. e.g.

```
void runner(int id, int a, int b) {...}
void runner2(int id) {...}

// I would wrap this in it's own class...
static ctpl::thread_pool pool(4);

void caller()
{
  int nbThreads = 25;
  for (int i = 0; i < nbThreads; i++) {
    pool.push(runner, a, b);
  }
}

// caller and caller2 called at different times in main thread.
void caller2(int jobs)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < jobs; i++) {
     pool.push(runner2);
   }
}
```

This example should synchronize all threads before the process ends.

---

Based on the answer you provided yourself, the functionality you desire seems to differ from what the library provides. The biggest issue is that if you're waiting in a for-loop you're wasting time. In your comment, you say that creating new threads every time you call `caller` would waste time. In your answer, what if results[0] takes ten minutes to run but rest of the results finished in seconds?

If you truly want to run N jobs and wait for them to be done while using the CTPL library. I recommend altering your answer a bit to at catch any exceptions that might have been thrown during the jobs.

```
void runner(int id, int a, int b) {...}

void caller()
{
  int jobs = 35;
  static ctpl::thread_pool pool(4);
  std::vector<std::future<void>> job_results;
  for (int i = 0; i < jobs; i++) {
    job_results.push_back(pool.push(runner, a, b));
  }
  for (std::future<void> result : job_results) {
    try {
      results.get();
    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
      ... // handle exception.
    }
  }
}
```

However, you would be best off just using a static vector of std::threads for the functionality you want. That way you don't have any 3rd party dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::future` to get the result of each thread. Then use `wait()` on `std::future` objects.

```
std::future<void> results[nbThreads];
for (int i=0; i<nbThreads; i++) results[i] = pool.push(runner, a, b);
for (int i=0; i<nbThreads; i++) results[i].wait(); // synchronize all threads
```