# Lambda expressions in thread pool in C++

Tags: c++, lambda, types, threadpool

I am trying to push a bunch of lambda expressions on a thread pool in C++. I know there are no in-built thread pool implementations in C++ (or at least that is what I read so far), so I used the one I found at: https://github.com/vit-vit/ctpl (I found it through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25684747/15033320) stackoverflow answer). I managed to use it when I had lambda expressions which would return basic C++ types (`int`, `double`, etc), but I cannot get it to work when I have a lambda expression which returns a custom class instance. I made a simple example to illustrate my problem, using this dummy class `Person`.

This is the dummy class `Person`:

```
class Person {
private:
    std::string name;
    int age;

public:
    Person(std::string name, int age) : name(std::move(name)), age(age) {}

    std::string getName() const { return name; }

    int getAge() const { return age; }
};
```

And I have this function in my `main` file which just creates an instance of the `Person` class:

```
Person generatePersonInstance(std::string name, int age) {
    return Person(std::move(name), age);
}
```

And then I just try to use the thread pool (again, the one I found at https://github.com/vit-vit/ctpl) with a lambda expression which returns a `Person` instance:

```
#include "ctpl_stl.h"
#include "Person.h"

int main() {
    std::string myName = "myName";
    int myAge = 100;

    ctpl::thread_pool pool(4);
    std::future<Person> f = pool.push([&myName, &myAge]{ generatePersonInstance(myName, myAge); });

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, I am trying to push on the thread pool a lambda expression which will just return a `Person` instance with the given parameters. The idea is that after this code runs, I can run `f.get()` to get the `Person` instance itself from the `std::future<Person>` instance. But my problem is that this code does not run, and I don't know why. At the `pool.push` part I get the error:

> No matching member function for call to 'push' candidate template
> ignored:  substitution failure [with F = (lambda at
> D:<my_path>\main.cpp:146:39), Rest = <>]: no matching function for
> call to object of type '(lambda at D:<my_path>\main... candidate
> template ignored: substitution failure [with F = (lambda at
> D:<my_path>\main.cpp:146:39)]: no matching function for call to
> object of type '(lambda at D:<my_path>\main.cpp:146:39)'

How can I fix this and make the code work as I intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 issues:

1. You're missing a `return` of `Person` in the lambda.
2. It looks like [the argument](https://github.com/vit-vit/CTPL/blob/master/ctpl_stl.h#L186) of `ctpl::push` must accept an `int` thread ID.

```cpp
std::future<Person> f = pool.push([&myName, &myAge](int id) {
    return generatePersonInstance(myName, myAge);
});
```